# opencart show a blankpage when a customer login

Tags: opencart

i,m using Opencart 1.5.6.1 for my store
everything is good, but when a customer register and then click the submit button OR when a customer want to login to own profile the page show blank
when the page is blank my URL is : www.mysite.com/index.php?route=account/login
Note: when blank page is showed, i reload the page, after reload everything works correctly and the next page shows!!
i enable error reporting in index.php and config files but doesn't show me any error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my problem
the problem is the my theme persian language
first reuploaded pesian language and doesn't fix my problem
then i edit only account>login language file and everything works correctly
the problem is related only to language files